# Does file uploading in Django have a delay before the user can see the uploaded files?

Tags: python, django

I have a typical `models.ModelForm` that has a single field: a `FileField`. However, when the user uploads a file using the form and the page reloads, the file is not listed. The user has to reload the page manually for it to appear as the "current file."

This is my view code:

```
submission = Submission.objects.filter(user=request.user, problem=problem).first()
    if request.POST:
        submission_form = SubmissionForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=submission)
        if submission_form.is_valid():
            submission_form.save()
    else:
        submission_form = SubmissionForm(instance=submission)
return render_to_response('view-problem.html',
                          dictionary={'problem': problem, 'submission_form': submission_form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My guess is that the file is still being processed while the view is loaded, so the user doesn't immediately see it. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new form after saving the old form.`ModelForm.save()` returns a model instance, you can use this instance to initialize the new ModelForm.

Code:

```
if request.POST:
    submission_form = SubmissionForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=submission)
    if submission_form.is_valid():
        submission = submission_form.save()

submission_form = SubmissionForm(instance=submission)
```